# Compiling a project that uses old-versioned Giraph with Maven

Tags: git, maven, compiler-errors, giraph

I have a project that was developed from another group and uses old-versioned Giraph.

The project is made based on the Giraph project itself; The project structure and files are exactly same to the Giraph, except that some .java sources for more complex map-reduce graph operation were defined in giraph-examples. As the project is an extension of the Giraph project, Maven is used to compile and package this project, which is also a building tool for Giraph project.

I can't find what version of Giraph this project was based on exactly, but I could find that compiling this project requires 0.2-SNAPSHOP of giraph-parent, and it is quite old one.

Current problem is that there's an error when I try to mvn verify;
mvn message printed on the screen is following :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order :
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core
[INFO] Apache Giraph Hive I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples
[INFO] Apache Giraph Accumulo I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph HBase I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph HCaatalog I/O
[INFO] 


[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building apache Giraph Parent 0.2-SNAPSHOP
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mavanagaiata:0.4.1:branch (git-commit) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent .................................... FAILURE [0.579s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Hive I/O .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Accumulo I/O .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph HBase I/O ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph HCatalog I/O .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.485s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 30 12.49.32 KST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.koraktor:mavanagaiata:0.4.1:branch (git-commit) on project giraph-parent: Unable to initialize Mojo: the gitDir /home/hduser/subgraphlisting/.git does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Also I could compile/package recent Giraph (from the official homepage) successfully using Maven in the same environment.
Error message says that there's no .git folder in my project folder, but there's only .svn folder.
Can somebody figure out the cause of this error exactly?

Thank you

Comment: Also I'd like to in which case a submodule(?) needs .git folder of the main project

Answer (score 0):

`mavanagaiata` is a maven plugin that adds git commit information to the build, so that you can later trace your artifacts back to a specific revision. If you're not building from inside of a git repository, then you will need to disable this feature. You can do so on a temporary basis by appending `-Dmavanagaiata.skipNoGit=true` to your `mvn` command execution.

More complete plug-in documentation can be found on [the plug-in website](http://koraktor.de/mavanagaiata/plugin-info.html).